# Python create md5, update and hexdigest in one line

Tags: python-3.x

I have been trying to create hashlib.md5(), invoking update() on it and then using hexdigest(), with weird behavior as shown bellow (second example, line 20).

[image]

- As you can see, a different approach in both line 19, and lines 21-23 work just fine.

I was curious, what is happening here and how one could replicate this behaviour.

Thanks,

Guy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

md5() returns the md5 class object and all of its functions and properties. This value is stored in your code for future reference.

It just so happens that you can also use this return piped into update(), because update() is a function of the class reference md5() return. However, update() does not return the classes self object (it actually returns None) from the md5 class so it cannot be piped into hexdigest().

If you wanted a single liner which does the desired behavior:

```
hashlib.md5(b'0').hexdigest()
```

Comment: As you can see in line 19, that's what I did too (suggested solution).
Regarding the "However, update() does not return the classes self object" I agree with your argument. Initially, I tried to go with the md5().update(b"0") and received the same error, but now trying to replicate it... nope. Guess a typo or something - Thx.